# Appropriate anchor settings for TableLayoutPanel to achieve desired behaviour

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, button, tablelayout

I am designing a form with WinForms, a partial screenshot of which is shown below:

[image]

The two buttons on the bottom are in a `tableLayoutPanel`, each one in its own cell. The "Add new baseline" button is anchored to the bottom and left, the "Delete Selected Baseline" button is anchored to the bottom and right. This partially does what I need it to do. That is, when the form is compressed horizontally, the buttons are also compressed, so that one doesn't overlap the other, for example.

They also need to stay in their exact positions as shown in the screenshot, when the form is resized vertically. At the moment, they are moving below and beyond the bottom edge of the form, or upwards and over the other button and the `listView` above. By the way, the `listView` is anchored to all sides.

I have tried several combinations of anchors for the `tableLayoutPanel`, and could not achieve the desired behaviour.

Comment: _"each one in its own cell"_ Then you don't need to use the `Anchor` property of the individual controls. Either set the `Anchor` property of the TableLayoutPanel to "all" (or whatever works for you) or set its `Dock` property to `Fill`.

Comment: I achieved the desired behaviour by setting the `TableLayoutPanel` `Dock` property to `Bottom`.